# Use PHP to find words with less than X characters in a text file

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

If i have a text list like this:

```
Coffee
Tea Cola
Juice
Beer
Vodka
Etc.
```

How do I use PHP to find all words with less than 4 characters and print them out?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so please tag it as such.

Comment: And show us what you've tried so far.  Of course PHP can do what you're asking.

Comment: Hmm.. Why do you vote this down? This is not homework, I just could not figure out how to do it, haven't tried anything, but the solution came quick here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$arr = file("words.txt");

foreach($arr as $word) {
    if(strlen($word) < 4) echo $word . "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: np, please mark some answer with 'V'

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `strlen` function - iterate through the words and filter out the ones with more characters.

```
foreach ($words as $singleWord)
{
   if ( strlen($singleWord) < 4 )
      echo $singleWord;
}
```